# Is 1-place relation just a single element set of N ？N is the set of natural numbers

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

I am confused about the 1-place relation. In the textbook, the definition of the 1-place relation is a subset of natural numbers.
In the book, {1} is a an example oof 1-place relation. So according to the definition, {1,2,3,4} is also a 1-place relation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by a "$1-$place relation"?  Edit your post to include a clear definition.

Comment: See [arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity). A one-place relation is a unary relation.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a $n$-place relation over a set of objects $x$ would be a set of $n$-tuples of the form $<x_1,x_2,...,x_n>$ where each of $x_i$ are elements from $X$.  We could also say that such a relation is a subset of the Cartesian product $X^n$

So, a $1$-place relation over a set $X$ would be a set of $1$-tuples $<x>$ with $x \in X$.  Since we typically consider a $1$-tuple $<x>$ simply as the object $x$ itself (and accordingly, consider $X^1$ to be $X$ itself)  this means that it such a relation would be a subset of $X$.

So yes, if we see $1$-tuples of objects simply as those very objects, then a $1$-place relation over the natural numbers would indeed just be a subset of the natural numbers. One such subset would indeed be $a$ with $a$ being some natural number.

Comment: ｛1｝and ｛1，2，3，4｝are both subset of N. Are they both 1-place relation？

Comment: @ZhanfengLi Yes, they are both 1-place relations